# i want to slide my slider by index of list which is in another page

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular2-forms

I want to use slideTo() function of list.ts by passing index of list which is in home.ts

**home.ts**

```
 export class HomePage {

              @ViewChild(Slides) slider: Slides;

            Something: string;
            newsData: any[];
            item: any;

            constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private httpProvider:HttpProvider )

            {
            }
              toggleDetails(newsData,i) {
                this.navCtrl.push(ListPage)

                ListPage.slider.slideTo(2, 500);
               }
             }
```

**list.ts**

```
 @ViewChild(Slides) slider: Slides;
         constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private httpProvider:HttpProvider) {
          this.getdata();
         }

         getdata(){
          this.httpProvider.getJsonData().subscribe(
            result => {
              this.newsData=result.response.data.newslist.news;

        },  
            err =>{
              console.error("Error : "+err);
            } ,
            () => {
              console.log('getData completed');
            }
          );
        }
         }
```

I want to open list.ts slider by index passing from list in home.ts

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? Are you saying you are in home.ts, then you want list.ts to open and slide to a specific value? OR are you saying list.ts is the active page, and you want to slide to a value that is in home.ts?

Comment: i have ion-list in home.ts is active page when user click on ion-list it get index. by that index in list.ts ion-slider will move to that specific index .